# Include Author profile in search results

Tags: search, user-roles

I need to add user profile to search results for a site we look after.  I need to return any user with role of 'Consultant' (and only consultant) whos name or nickname or whatever matches the search request.

You can browse to a consultant page on the site which shows their details but I need it to be included in the search, and am finding it increasingly difficult.

I have tried writing a complex(ish) sql query to fetch out the user id's from the database where the first_name or last_name LIKE '%s%' and where the wp_capabilities is LIKE '%consultant%' which does work to an extend, but I don't know what to do with it now.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to create individual user search system for only with user data or just want to include user data in default search stem of the WP have ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a user *role* called "consultant" and you do a search filtering by *capability* "consultant", you wouldn't find anything. Roles and capabilities are different things. Here is the codex reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter, along with [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), to alter the query that's exposed on your theme's search.php.

I'm interested in seeing how this could be achieved, so I've decided to strap on my proverbial rucksack and do some fiddling. If I get anywhere, I'll post my results here.

Comment: Please do let me know if you find a solution to this.

Comment: I will! There's quite a lot of threads out there for this same request, but most suggest plugins, so in a pinch, you could go that route.